# resolving network shortcut

Tags: delphi, winapi

I added some FTP servers via network shortcuts to windows.

How can I get the FTP address via the WinAPI?

With SHGetFolderPath / CSIDL_NETHOOD, I can get the location of the target.lnk file. But how can I get the FTP URL of that file?

A "normal" .lnk file, I can resolve with this:

```
  ShellLink := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink) as IShellLink;
  ShellLink.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, PersistFile);
  PersistFile.Load('C:\Test.lnk', STGM_READ);
  ShellLink.Resolve(WindowHandle, 0);
  Filename[0] := #0;
  ShellLink.GetPath(PChar(@Filename[0]), Length(Filename), pfd, 0);
```

... but this does not work for the Target.lnk files of the network shortcuts to ftp://host/ adresses.

Comment: Maybe because of note [_"You cannot use IShellLink to create a link to a URL."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891(v=vs.85).aspx) you cannot even read..

Comment: @Victoria That is simply not true, it is unusual but they can contain URLs. And if you can read you will see that the OP did not say they created it, they just want to read it.

Comment: @Anders, I said that maybe you cannot read URL links because the note mentioned in the linked article says you cannot create such. That links can contain URL is fine, but can you you at least read them by the `IShellLink` interface? You know how as it seems, so post an answer then..

Comment: @Victoria I had already started writing my answer but I had to step through the function in the debugger first to verify my assumptions.

Comment: @Anders, so you cannot read URL link with `IShellLink` interface? If no, I was not so wrong.

Comment: @Victoria Yes you can. The URL is stored as a id-list in the .lnk and GetIDList works just fine. You just can't read it with the GetPath method because a URL is not a file system path.

Comment: @Anders, thank you! Shall we delete comments from here then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IShellLink::GetPath` is used to retrieve a file system path (only drive letter or UNC roots). This is not clear from the documentation but it uses `SHGetPathFromIDListEx` internally and MSDN has this to say about that function:

> Converts an item identifier list to a file system path

If you want the raw shortcut target your best bet is usually `IShellLink::GetIDList`. You can get the parsing name by using [`SHGetNameFromIDList(..., SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762191(v=vs.85).aspx) on the id-list.