# SHGetNameFromIDList fails for FTP PIDLs

Tags: winapi, com, shell32

If I add an FTP network location on Windows, it creates a .lnk file pointing to the location. If I open the link via *IShellLink*, obtain its *IShellFile* target, and bind it to *IShellFolder*, I can enumerate the files on the remote location (after logging in) using *IShellFolder::EnumObjects*, and the correct files are returned.

However, if I try to obtain a name of any file there, via *SHGetNameFromIDList* or *IShellItem::GetDisplayName*, the function fails with `0x80070057` (invalid parameter) HRESULT. I know for sure that the PIDL is valid, because I can construct *IShellItem*, and its size is 72 bytes, but any attempt to obtain the path fails. Accessing any properties I can think of on *IShellItem2*, constructed from the PIDL, also fails, as well as simply calling *SHGetPathFromIDList*.

So, how do I obtain any meaningful name from the PIDL, preferably in `SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEPARSING`? Why do all these operations fail? I thought any PIDL is at least a file path or a CLSID, but this PIDL simply cannot be queried for anything.

I am aware that there are tons of better solutions for accessing FTP, but I have this question for Shell32 in general, not for FTP specifically.

I have also converted the PIDL to bytes via *ILSaveToStream*, and I can see the name of the file is *definitely* there.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196480/7571258) suggests that `SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING` should work.

Comment: @zett42 Sadly, this also fails with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that *IShellFolder::EnumObjects* returned relative PIDLs. For some reason, names of relative FTP PIDLs cannot be obtained, although they are clearly stored in the *SHITEMID*.

Well, calling *ILCombine* on the folder and file PIDLs made everything work as expected.

Comment: This is clearly documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761983.aspx "The ITEMIDLIST structures returned in the array are relative to the IShellFolder being enumerated.". pidls are 100% opaque, they can contain anything, not only names, path or CLSIDs. So you *must* combine what's returned from EnumObjects with the folder's absolute pidl if you want to use static methods like SHGetPathFromIDList. However, IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf should work with relative pidls (not to be confused with IShellItem's)